# Trying to install Elementary OS, cannot click

Tags: system-installation, mouse, touchpad

I am attempting to install OS Luna elementary to replace my busted Windows 10 OS. However, I have encountered a very vexing problem - I am in the installation stage and cannot click anything. I can move the cursor with the trackpad, but clicking produces no results. This would not be as much of a problem if installation windows did not appear offscreen - since I cannot click on them, I cannot drag them back on screen so I can interact with them. I have attempted to plug in and use a wireless mouse, but this has the same problem: I can move the cursor, but can't click. Does anyone know what I can do to either get the click working, or to somehow move the installation windows back on screen? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It might not help you in your specific situation with an installation about to bust. But for an installation of a new operating system I would never use devices such as trackpads or a wireless mouse as you never know if and how they are supported, i.e. drivers are provided. Just connect a regular keyboard and mouse, get everything running and then look for additional drivers.

If you are going to REPLACE Win10 why dont you just cancel the installation and start from the beginning even if the existing Win10 installation might already been corrupted. Take either a Live CD or - in case you do not have an optical drive - create a bootable USB-stick and boot from the PC from the respective medium. With elementary OS running from the CD (or USB medium) check everything (screen output, keyboard, mouse, network connection, ..). If your trackpad or whatever other device works here it should do so during and after installation as well. If everything works fine AND if you are not heading for an installation parallel to another OS AND if you are not familiar with setting up partitions etc. just let the installer on the live CD do the installation.

And a final point: "Luna" is an old version of elementary OS. <s>"Freya"</s> "Loki" is the latest version. There is no upgrade from Luna to Loki. The latter needs a fresh install. What could be a reason not to install the latest version?

Comment: As of this month, Loki is now the latest version of elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

Before selecting the option to boot from live USB. Press the Button "e" and you'll get Grub Editor.

Find the line ending with `quiet splash`

Add `nomodeset` before `quiet splash` so that now it looks like
 [.....]`nomodeset quiet splash`

Press Ctrl+x to boot now and repeat the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 : Better you use tab key and spacebar key to select or click.

Method 2 : Move the cursor over the object and press space bar key to select or click.

After installation - go to system settings - mouse settings; there you can enable mouse click.

Try it.
(sorry for my bad English)